# what is java clsid ? where can I find or write clsid for any java version?

Tags: java, clsid

I have a problem with run jar file ..... please explain this CLSID

```
"jpi_classid=clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
```

what is...  **"8AD9C840"** , **"044E"**, **"11D1"**, **"B3E9"**, **"00805F499D93"** whare to come this code how to write this or whare i can find it java version wise .....

Now my question is if the java version changed then how can I edit this **CLSID code** ...

Comment: Try this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/family-clsid-140615.html

Comment: already found this link but not helpful to my question.... what CLSID if jre version 1.7.0_79

Answer (score 0):

The CLSID of **8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93** is a special identifier (like a magic number). It tells Java to use the highest installed version on the system.

For Example:

- If I had both Java 6 update 47 and java 8 update 181 - the system would use Java 8 update 181.
- If I only had Java 6 update 47 - the system would use Java 6
  update 47.

If you want the system to look for a specific Java version, you would need to use the CLSID in the following format (Java 8 update 181 given): **CAFEEFAC-0018-0000-0181-ABCDEFFEDCBA**

If you want the system to look for the highest version of a specific family, you would need to use the CLSID in the following format (Java 8 any update given): **CAFEEFAC-0018-0000-FFFF-ABCDEFFEDCBA**